# Magento 2 : di.xml on custom param won't work

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, di

I've a class located in \Vendor\Module\Model which is named Test.
Here is the constructor of this class :

```
public function __construct(array $map = [])
{
    var_dump($map);
    die;
}
```

I created a di.xml located in \OtherVendor\OtherModule\etc\di.xml
I put in :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
    <type name="Vendor\Module\Model\Test">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="map" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="test" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="test" xsi:type="string">test</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Do you have an idea why on my constructor $map is empty?

---

Here is the code of my class :

```
<?php

namespace Test\ImportExport\Model\Import;

class SourceConverterAdapter
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_map;

    /**
     * Factory constructor
     *
     * @param array $map
     */
    public function __construct(array $map = [])
    {
        $this->_map = $map;
    }

    public function process($needle)
    {
        var_dump($this->_map);
        return 1;
    }
}


<type name="Test\ImportExport\Model\Import\SourceConverterAdapter">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="map" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="test" xsi:type="string">hello</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

Comment: add your OtherVendor\OtherModule\Model\Test code in question

Comment: I replaced <item name="test" xsi:type="string">test</item> and it's the same. Then it doesn't come from the other class

Comment: Did you cleared cache?

Comment: I've all caches disabled, i run a setup:di:compile and i'm in developer mode. Have you reproduced ?

Comment: Change  `__construct(array $map = [])` to `__construct(array $map )` and can try with `private $map;
public function __construct(array $map)
{
  $this->map = $map;
}`

Comment: I have try your code and seems i am getting array with test inside test. can you please add your  \Vendor\Module\Model\Test whole code @help

Answer (score 0):

Variable name in constructor resides in the global scope as part of constructor signature so while referring to your param you need to provide the same variable name, otherwise, it will just take up default value you've provided in the constructor. Change di.xml as follows;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
    <type name="Vendor\Module\Model\Test">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="map" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="test" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="test" xsi:type="string">test</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**EDIT :**
Just realized you've written right config. Just FYI di compile triggers recompiles the di.xml in all the registered modules that's why it may not be reflecting before.